# Play-Json Coast-to-Coast: Best Pattern for "Nesting" Transformations

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm becoming a fan of the play-json coast-to-coast pattern, especially its use of combinators. I have some complex cases I'm munging together. I know there's a better way, but I'm new to the combinator approach to build up functionality.

I'd like to turn this:

```
{
 "somearray": [
   { 
     "field1": "value1",
     "field2": "value1",
     "key": "key1"
   },
   { 
     "field1": "second1",
     "field2": "second1",
     "key": "key2"
   }
  ]
 }
```

into this:

```
{
 "someObj": {
   "key1":
   { 
     "field1": "value1",
     "field2": "value1"
   },
   "key2":
   { 
     "field1": "second1",
     "field2": "second1"
   }
  ]
 }
```

I can get this to work, but I exit out of the transformation:

```
 (__ \ "someObj").json.copyFrom(__ \ "someArray".json.pick.map {
   case JsArray(arr) => {
     JsObject(arr.map(a =>
       a.transform(<A transform function to prune key>).map(pruned => {
         ((a \ "key").as[String], pruned)
       }).flatMap({
         case JsSuccess(result, _) => Seq(result)
         case other => Nil
       })
   }
   case other => JsNull
 })
```

THere are some issues with this code: I know it's verbose, I know I'm assume "key" is present with a string type, and I need that flatMap to get me out of a JsResult and into some JsValue I can use to build the JsObject.

It seems like I should be able to

1) Create a sub transformation, i.e. `a.transform()` can be nestled in the parent transform without unpacking and repacking the json object.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest to have a look at JsZipper by Mandubian: http://mandubian.com/2013/05/01/JsZipper/ This made our life much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (ignoring the fact that this code still has the same issues you already mentioned)?

```
 def elementTransform = for {
    keyValue <- (__ \ 'key).json.pick  // picks value for key field
    obj <- (__ \ 'key).json.prune // returns object without the key field
    res <- (__ \ keyValue.as[String]).json.put(obj) // uses the keyValue as a field name
  } yield res

  val transform = (__ \ "someObj").json.copyFrom((__ \ "someArray").json.pick[JsArray].map(
    _.value.foldLeft[JsResult[JsObject]](JsSuccess(Json.obj()))(
      (obj, a) =>
        for {
          o <- obj
          field <- a.transform(elementTransform)
        } yield o ++ field
    ).fold(_ => JsNull, identity)
  ))
```